# Discord.py embed is only showing one word

Tags: discord.py

So I'm trying to make a !say (message goes here) command for my discord bot. Here's the code I've got so far:

```
async def say(ctx, message):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="New Say Message", description=(message), color=0xff0000)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

If I do "!say Hello", it works fine. However, if I do "!say How are you", it just shows the word "How" in the embed. Here's what I mean: https://gyazo.com/b146fff6c1d7c99a47db9c218dd753f1.

What do I need to do/change to make it show the full message. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your function signature is set up incorrectly. You only accept one argument from the bot with `async def say(ctx, message)`; in order to consume a variable-length of arguments in python, you need `*`. Then you would consume that variable length as a list.

Example:

```py
async def say(ctx, *message):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="New Say Message", description=(" ".join(message)), color=0xff0000)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Thanks you! One last thing, how would I make it accept numerous lines and not show them all together. EG:

!say Hello (new line)

How are you

Shows as: "Hello How are you" on one line.

Is there a way to make it do different lines if that's how the !say message was written? Thanks

Comment: @JackThorn just to be clear, you want the bot to send separate embedded messages based on the newline character? If so, you would split the message by newline, and in the function send while or for-loop that sends separate `embed` for `ctx.send()`

Comment: Not a new embed, just a new line in the same embed if I do a new line while writing !say. Like this: https://gyazo.com/8cb854053b20c9019d9f5b10c2e826e6 (I know I've changed the command and a few words but it's the same code)

Comment: @JackThorn the bot will not capture that as a newline character. You will have to feed in the actual newline character `\n`

Comment: I'm really sorry but I don't quite understand. I thought this might be what you meant - https://gyazo.com/ea03aad1b0272baf9e3a1072ef591092, but clearly it isn't. Can you explain what I would have to add/change in my code to allow new messages. For an example, here's what I'm trying to achieve: https://gyazo.com/28dd0c638fa4ed651ea8749035206508, however this is what happens: https://gyazo.com/455adceca4ee040c0788acffa8de0d17

Comment: @JackThorn If that is your intention, perhaps you should be using `fields` instead of `description`

Comment: Ok, sounds like a plan. How do I make it so each newline of !say appears as a new field?

Comment: @JackThorn Actually given the text format of what you want, `fields` may not be the best. So to pivot back, in your `description`, the newline character `\n` would have to done within the code itself i.e. `"\n".join(message)`. The bot will not read in newline characters from chat for multiple security reasons. Given your text format, you will have be more specific than `"\n".join(message)` and add the newline character appropriately.